# What's command to change the commit in the HEAD file without changing any other files?

Tags: git, git-merge

What's command to change the commit in the ".git\HEAD" file without changing any other files?
I needed files from one branch, but the Head points to another

Comment: `git checkout THE_BRANCH`? I'm not quite sure if that answers what you want, because I'm not quite sure what you're asking.

Comment: This command will not only change the HEAD, but also change the files of my project, which I don't need.

Comment: This smells like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info). **Why** do you want to change `.git/HEAD`. What is your end goal?

Comment: What do you want to achieve with this? (XY problem flag rising) (hey @JoachimSauer seems we're synchronized :-) )

Comment: Are you wanting to change branch, but keep file changes?

Comment: @RomainValeri I want to see what the result of merging one branch into another will be, but I don't want to do that merge yet.

Comment: @Ilya you can merge without committing. `git merge <branch_name> --no-commit`

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to check the outcome of a merge, you could just do the merge. If it is successful you can undo it with `git reset HEAD^1`. If it fails with conflicts you can go back with `git merge --abort`. Another possibility is doing a merge without commit as @evolutionxbox suggested (`git merge <branch_name> --no-commit`).